# Is it possible to use NSKeyedArchiver to store an animated UIImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsarchiving

I loaded an image using frames downloaded from a web server.

```
NSArray* frames = [self fetchFramesFromServer];
imageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithImages:frames duration:1.0];
```

Whenever I try to archive these frames, the encoding function returns NO:

```
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:(frames) toFile:archivePath];
```

Whenever I try to archive the image, the encoding function also returns NO:

```
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:(imageView.image) toFile:archivePath];
```

Is this even possible, or am I missing some caveat of archiveRootObject that requires the UIImage to be loaded from the bundle, in png-format, or non-animated?

Just FYI, the archivePath when printed out in the debugger is

```
NSPathStore2 * @"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E475E3C1-4E3F-43D6-AD66-0F98320CF279/Library/Private Documents/assets/a/b/c.archive"   0x000000012c555a60
```

UPDATE:

I am storing the individual frames of the animation inside a for-loop, but I get the following:

```
+ (void) saveImage:(UIImage*)inputImage
    withSuffix:(NSString*)fileSuffix
{
if (inputImage == nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: input image is nil!");
    return;
}

// strip away intermediate folders to avoid over-nesting
// ex: __F1/MF/FR/1_MF_FR_Animation_a1.png
// ===> 1_MF_FR_Animation_a1.png
NSString* suffixStub = [MyDatabase stubOfFilepath:fileSuffix];

NSURL* url = [MyDatabase folderURL];
NSURL* imageURL = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:suffixStub];

NSData* pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(inputImage);
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:pngData toFile:imageURL.path];
pngData = nil;

NSLog(@"Image %@ successfully saved!", fileSuffix);
}
```

But on the NSKeyedArchiver line, I get "malloc: *** error for object 0x178202340: Freeing unallocated pointer"

Comment: Do not archive images. Store the images on disk and archive their names.

Comment: So in my example, if I got my image through AFNetworking, which already writes the file to the documents folder [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/imageName.png"]; then you'd recommend archiving the NSString filePath and then after unarchiving the file name, reading from that location with [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:unarchivedPath]?

Comment: Just FYI, I also found out that my example was not working because archivePath contained a bunch of nested folders.  If I just append to the documents URL once, it works...

Comment: Actually, why even archive the names?  If I can generate the path from the name of the image I want, I can just archive an NSNumber boolean @0 or @1 to tell if the image has been downloaded or not.... right?

Answer (score 0):

First convert your image to NSData and then try archiving it

```
NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:archivePath];
```

In case of `NSArray`, archiving is possible only if all the objects of array conforms to `NSCoding` protocol. If your array has custom object refer [Custom object archiving](https://blog.soff.es/archiving-objective-c-objects-with-nscoding) on how to conform to `NSCoding`.

**UPDATE**

If objects of your array are frames of type `CGRect` the you can use `NSStringFromCGRect()` and `CGRectFromString()` to store and then retrieve them.

Comment: I did this for every frame, inside a for-loop:

+ (void) saveImage:(UIImage*)inputImage
        withSuffix:(NSString*)fileSuffix;
{
    // strip away intermediate folders to avoid over-nesting
    NSString* suffixStub = [MyDatabase stubOfFilepath:fileSuffix];
    
    NSURL* url = [MyDatabase folderURL];
    NSURL* imageURL = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:suffixStub];
    
    NSData* pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(inputImage);
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:pngData toFile:imageURL.path];
}

But malloc: *** error for object 0x178202340: Freeing unallocated pointer